# Gunicorn Nginx host two websites - Gunicorn creates a sock file only for one

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Ubuntu server on which I'm trying to host two Django applications using Gunicorn and Nginx.
When I have only one website hosted all works fine. Gunicorn creates a .sock file and nginx redirects to it.
The problem I have is that I have a gunicorn config file for the second site and that doesn't create a .sock file therefore I get a bad gateway error.
Here are my files:
Gunicorn.conf

```
description "David Bien com application"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid www-data
chdir /home/ubuntu/davidbien

exec venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/davidbien/davidbien.sock davidbiencom.wsgi:application
```

The above file works fine. The second one:
Gunicorn1.conf

```
description "Projects"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid www-data
chdir /home/user/dbprojects

exec virtual/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/dbprojects/dbproject.sock dbproject.wsgi:application
```

This one doesn't create the .sock file. I tried restarting gunicorn and even tried running the second file only by running sudo service gunicorn1 start but I get:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

In the logs there's nothing mentioning the second file running.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just noticed a typo in my config file

```
chdir /home/user/dbprojects
```

Should be ubuntu no user. This can be closed.